# Ascending order has strange effects on wordpress loop

Tags: loop, wp-query, order

I have a custom loop:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'symposia_program',
    'taxonomy' => 'days', 
    'term' => 'day-1',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        .....(code)....
    endwhile; 
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

For some reason, the `'order' => 'ASC'` parameter has strange effects on the output of the loop. Basically it doesn't render some of the posts, namely some recent ones. If I switch back to `DESC`, all the posts show up. Please help!

Comment: `taxonomy` is depreciated, you should switch to `tax_query`. Also, I do not believe `term` is an actual parameter.

Comment: Thanks. That didn't seem to be the problem though. It seems the problem is solved by adding 'posts_per_page' => -1 which forces wordpress to show all posts matching the parameters. Here's my final code:'post_type' => 'symposia_program', 
   'days' => $progDay,
   'meta_key' => 'class_number', 
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'ASC',

   'posts_per_page'=> -1 );

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is solved by adding `'posts_per_page' => -1` which forces WordPress to show all posts matching the parameters. Here's my final code:

```
array ( 
    'post_type'      => 'symposia_program', 
    'days'           => $progDay, 
    'meta_key'       => 'class_number', 
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order'          => 'ASC', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1 
);
```